# Writing an Algorithm for maximum likelihood estimation in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, maximize

I know that MATLAB has a package for maximum likelihood estimation, but for educational purposes I'm writing by myself an algorithm that gives me back estimates. Now, I have written a function that I'm trying to minimize (since I'm using the negative log likelihood). Here it is:

```
function ml = two_var(param, data)
mu = param(1);
sigma = param(2);
n=numel(data);
sumto = 0;
for i=1:n
    c = data(i)- mu;
    sumto = sumto + c;
    ml = n/2*log(2*pi)+n/2*log(sigma^2)+1/(2*sigma^2)*sumto^2;
end
```

This code concerns the estimation of a gaussian distibution. Now, the problem that I have is that this function does not seem to be a valid `fminunc` input... How can I circumvert the problem? What am I doing wrong? Thanks to anybody who wants to help ;)

Comment: My thesis is stuck at pretty much similar stage. ;)

Comment: why is it not a valid input? A way of circumventing the problem is writing your own minimization function instead of using matlabs inbuilt....

Comment: Have you called fminunc with `fminunc(@(param) two_var(param, data), param0 )` ?

Comment: Yes... It tells me "failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation. FMINUNC cannot continue."

Comment: Maybe the initial guess is not good enough, and this caused a NaN or Inf ml. You might try to use fmincon, since its interior-point algorithm can recover from these situations.

Comment: I don't know how to handle the problem, even with `fmincon` since I'm trying to estimate values from a vector generated with `data = random('norm',0,1,[400,1])`... Then, the maximum of the function should be located near [0,1], and even setting "dummy constraints", with the initial guess of [0,1] doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: Your loop does not really make sense. Take a look what is happening to `sumto` - on each step of the loop, you are adding `c` to it, and then computing again the variable `ml` (whose value at the final iteration is what your function will return). You should probably get rid of the loop altogether and just apply vectorized operations to `data`. Then use `sum` to compute the value of the likelihood function.

Comment: An example would be greatly appreciated ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everybody that helped in commenting the question. Well, I have used all your useful comments in order to improve my code. Here is my final result.

```
function ml = t_var(param)
rng default;
data = random('norm',0,1,[400,1]);
z = (data - param(1)) ./ param(2);
L = -.5.*z.*z - log(sqrt(2.*pi).*param(2));
ml = -sum(numel(data).*L);
```

This code is undoubtedly easier to read; moreover, it makes use of the fast vector operations that are allowed in MATLAB. After defining this function, is then easy to call it with

```
x0 =[0 0]
[x,fval] = fminsearch(@t_var,x0,optimset('TolX',1e-19,'MaxFunEvals',1000,'MaxIter',1000))
```

And obtain ML estimates that are consistent with the ones that you can get otherwise.

Thanks a lot to everybody who gave me some hints! ;)